# Как создать полноценный вебсервер игры на node.js

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, socket.io

я начинающий разработчик, у меня есть цель: создать полноценный сервер для браузерной игры (допустим, для игры в дурака, а игры между пользователями организованы в комнатах).
Реализовать это дело я решил на node.js.
Я изучил много разных гайдов, нашел даже книжки по ноде, их тоже прочитал. Но на некоторые вопросы я не нашел ответов, можете поделиться ссылками на материалы по следующим темам?

1. Как я должен обрабатывать аварийные ситуации? Как избежать потери информации? Как вообще-то планово остановить сервер для каких-то технических работ? Ну чтоб не просто обрубить всем соединения, а дать доиграть людям до конца и тогда уже скинуть.
2. Как я могу посчитать сколько пользователей выдержит моя игра? Что делать если максимальное значение пользователей достигнуто, а они валят еще? Могу ли я как-то не дать им заходить? Что в таких ситуациях принято делать?
3. Как правильно организовать комнаты в игре? Мне кажется, если я создам список с комнатами, в котором буду хранить информацию обо всех комнатах и о состоянии дел в каждой конкретной комнате, то случится что-то страшное. Я ведь буду менять эту информацию из разных концов программы. А там же все асинхронно. К примеру, что в голову приходит - состояние в комнате изменилось, я лезу менять количество ходов или что-то еще у игрока, а он в этот момент вышел и функция в другом конце программы очистила все его данные.

Ну и еще куча вопросов про безопасность и ресурсы. Сколько потребляет мое приложение, если я хочу арендовать вебсервер, то на какие параметры стоит обратить внимание? Нода же не работает с памятью, но так или иначе она ее использует.

Об этом всем я не видел ничего в уроках, видеоуроках, книжках по Ноде. Где можно получить более что ли боевую, житейскую информацию про создание вебсерверов? Понимаю, что это скорее всего уже передается от более опытных товарищей к менее опытным в боевых условиях. Но это для меня совсем не подходит, хотелось бы разобрать теоретический материал на эту тему.

Answer (score 3):

Поробую дать несколько советов. Поскольку вы начинающий программист то не следует слишком усложнять все, а наоборот упрощайте.

> Как я должен обрабатывать аварийные ситуации? Как избежать потери
> информации? Как вообще-то планово остановить сервер для каких-то
> технических работ? Ну чтоб не просто обрубить всем соединения, а дать
> доиграть людям до конца и тогда уже скинуть.

Аварийные ситуации бывают разными. Дать однозначно сходу ответ не получится. Всё индивидуально одно дело потеря сессии другое не достаточно памяти.

Остановить планово сервер, в вашем случае это не давать создавать новых столов - т.е. тот или другой endpoint, будет возращать не возможно присоединится или создать игру с некоторым сообщением. Дождаться окончания всех игр (не всегда это возможно) либо оборвать сессии после определённого времени дав при этом время (10 либо 20 минут это как удобно, главное предупредить) на завершение игры.

> Как я могу посчитать сколько пользователей выдержит моя игра? Что
> делать если максимальное значение пользователей достигнуто, а они
> валят еще? Могу ли я как-то не дать им заходить? Что в таких ситуациях
> принято делать?

Тут про100 так дать ответ не удастся, машины, сервера хостинг он различный. Совет не заморачиваться в начале на этом. Это часть проблем развертывания игры - поверьте если у вас будет очень хорошая игра и люди побегут рекой, то решением вашего вопроса можно будет заняться в плотную.

> Как правильно организовать комнаты в игре? Мне кажется, если я создам
> список с комнатами, в котором буду хранить информацию обо всех
> комнатах и о состоянии дел в каждой конкретной комнате, то случится
> что-то страшное. Я ведь буду менять эту информацию из разных концов
> программы. А там же все асинхронно. К примеру, что в голову приходит -
> состояние в комнате изменилось, я лезу менять количество ходов или
> что-то еще у игрока, а он в этот момент вышел и функция в другом конце
> программы очистила все его данные.

Не усложняйте, вы тем самым настраиваетесь на неудачу. Подумаешь что комнат несколько сотен тысяч, и что? Если для вас это сложно начните с 3 комнат двух или вовсе одной. Понятно что всё асинхронно, и то что состояние меняется со всех уголков вселенной так это нормально. Каждый клиент получает состояние с сервера и меняет его когда пришел его ход. На счет гипотетических функций - так вот ничего гипотетического не происходит, а происходит ровно то что вы реализовали. Если вы сделали что после выхода кого-то или другого события будет очистка, то поверьте так оно и будет.

На счет всякой кучи вопросов. Решайте их последовательно по мере возникновения, вы начинающий программист (деплоймент это не начало) и поверьте учится на чужих ошибках человечество пока не научилось. Учится будите только на своих, вы пропустите через себя большинство из них, за исключением тех которые имеют готовое эталонное решение. Я понимаю что многие ошибки хотелось бы избежать, в таком случае откуда взять опыт?

**PS.** Мнение моё личное и не согласным можно добавить свой ответ, благо это не зависит от меня.